# Impersonation is required - HTTP Error 500.24

Tags: .net, iis, impersonation, windows-server-2016

I have a site that uses Windows authentication in an intranet and the application requires impersonation as part of its functionality. When accessing it via a domain url(still in the intranet) I'm getting an 500.24 error.

Of course turning off impersonation removes the error but the application doesn't work. Anyone know how to keep impersonation on and stop the 500.24 error? Every solution I find is to turn off impersonation but this application requires it.

Answer (score 0):

This was what I was looking for.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/> 
</system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to acess IIS Management of Windows

In the top left side menu, select the server, in my case it was my localhost.

Below in the IIS quadrant you must click on Authentication, a window will open.

In this new window you must:

1 - Look for the ASP.NET Impersonation fields and check if it is disabled, as it must be disabled for IIS to work in your Visual Studio debugger

2 - Anonymous authentication must be enabled.